# Properties of semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G,K $ and $H$ are finite groups, will this property holds?

$G\cap(H\rtimes K)= (G\cap H) \rtimes (G\cap K)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I suppose those are **subgroups** of some bigger group, right? Otherwise I'm not sure what you expect those intersections to be, for example...

Comment: In addition to previous comments, you also need to specify what the actions are (that define the semi-direct products).

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I believe that OP is asking whether it holds for any action (since $K$ acts on $H$, we have $G\cap K$ acts on $G\cap H$ so in fact there is only one action).

Comment: @Levent I'm not sure the OP is very knowable of what (s)he is asking, otherwise (s)he'd add some relevant information to the question.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have to agree.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the question is really about but I will give a counter-example as I understood. Consider $S_3$ and set $G=\{1,(12)\},H=\{1,(123),(132)\}$ and $K=\{1,(13)\}$. Then $HK=S_3$ so $G\cap HK=G$ but $G\cap H=G\cap K=1$ so we get the trivial subgroup on the right hand side.

In general, the right hand side is always a subgroup of the left hand side but the equality holds in some special cases. You can check Dedekind's Lemma.

Comment: Suppose $G = \langle a \rangle \rtimes \langle b \rangle = \langle a,b| a^{m}=1, b^{n}=1, b^{-1}ab = a^{r} \rangle$, and $H\leq G$ which one of the following will hold
$N_G(H)\cap (\langle a \rangle \rtimes \langle b \rangle) = (N_G(H) \cap \langle a \rangle) \rtimes (N_G(H)\cap \langle b \rangle) $ or $C_G(H)\cap (\langle a \rangle \rtimes \langle b \rangle) = (C_G(H) \cap \langle a \rangle) \rtimes (C_G(H)\cap \langle b \rangle) $

Comment: What do you think? You don't show any effort, or gratitude of any kind.

Comment: I cannot find it in any textbook, i tried show this but it was a failure, my bad.

Comment: None of them holds in the above example. Take $G=S_3$ which is the semidirect product of $\langle (123)\rangle$ and $\langle (13)\rangle$. Take $H=\langle (12)\rangle$. Then $N_G(H)=C_G(H)=H$.